# Rounded corners in metaslider wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is there a way to make the corners of a Wordpress Metaslider plugin rounded with border radius. When you create a new Metaslider you have advanced menu and there is an option to add CSS classes.

But when I add the CSS class border-radius it does not work. Then I tried to just add code in this option but that also did not work.

```
.border-radius{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:    10px;
     border-radius:        10px;
 }
```

Am I doing something wrong or should this work?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. You only need to find the css class of the slider and add rounded corners in that class. In my case this code worked for me.

```
.nivoSlider {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:    10px;
    border-radius:         10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to: Appearance->Additional CSS: then paste this CSS code:

```
#content .wpb_alert p:last-child, 
#content .wpb_text_column :last-child, 
#content .wpb_text_column p:last-child, 
.wpb_alert p:last-child, 
.wpb_text_column :last-child, 
.wpb_text_column p:last-child { 
    margin-bottom: 16px;    
    border-radius: 24px;
}
```